# How to format the actual Drive in my laptop if I want to change it for a new one

Tags: format

I have a serious problem I had the window 11 Pro install into a hard drive I removed the drive I changed it for a new one then I tried to format the old drive with window inside and I received message error

Comment: What type of drive is the old one? And how is it being connected to the laptop?

Comment: No I have two HDD with windows 11 pro installed on  each one. The old one is 1 TB and  the new one is a 500GB I would like to keep the 1TB as an external drive but when I tried to format it it doesn't work.  Obviously the disc is not damaged because I put it back in the laptop and it worked perfectly as it was before the fact that you take it take it out physically from the laptop and you try to format it as an external you received the the message cyclic redundary I'm very confused right now because I want to erase it and I cannot thank you for your help

Comment: What type of drive is it though. 2.5" / M.2, SATA or NVMe etc. And what hardware are you using to connect it to your laptop?

Comment: The drive with Windows installed booting in its original connection doesn't mean it has no problems. Assuming for the moment it's fine the next potential problem is whatever the adapter you're using for external use (unfortunately the answer you got so far and the replies in comments don't address this). Please [edit] and add that info.

Comment: The problem is without knowing which adapter the author has been using that answer doesn't make much sense. Many (most) cheap USB-SATA adapters don't support SMART or chkdsk. And very likely the error is because of the adapter so even if it could do what you suggest there still would be problem.

Comment: Not at all picky. Please read again and understand it *may* not even work for error correction. It certainly can't if the interface itself is faulty and **the interface (enclosure, cable, dock, whatever...) being faulty is by far the most likely scenario here**. Any answer no addressing this is a bad answer, especially after the OP informed about CRC errors that you chalked immediately and condescendingly to a drive fault.

Comment: If you're seeing a diamond (mod) badge in my username you should have your eyes checked.

Comment: "and I received message error" - **What error?** [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the new drive and put the old one aside for the time being.

**(1) Getting going:**

Since the machine already was Windows 11 Pro, it will activate just fine with the new drive.

Install the new drive, download the Windows 11 Pro ISO from the Microsoft Downloads site onto a bootable USB Key (Windows should do that for you). Start the computer with the USB in the machine and run Setup on the USB to begin the installation.

**(2) Using the old drive:**

Once running, if you need data from the old drive, put it in a USB Drive Carrier that you can plug into the laptop and recover data you need.

Once you have the drive in the carrier, you can also format it as you wish, assuming the drive is in good condition.

You can (carefully) run CHDSK on the old drive. It may be the drive died causing the initial issue with Windows 11 problems on the old drive. Just evaluate the drive as best you can and perhaps do not depend upon it for the long term.

Since the drive at least works, you can put it back in the computer and use the Windows ISO to delete partitions and set it up again. See if that works. This may allow you to format the drive as an external drive.

Comment: It's kind of too late right now I physically removed the disc HDD from the laptop with window 11 already installing it I changed the hard drive and I reinstall window in it now I would like to format the disk that is out of the laptop and use it as a external drive. I don't understand that when I tried to format that disc it doesn't appear we cannot see it I go with the disc management and window 11 and I received the error of the cyclic I really don't understand why I cannot format that this normally I'm French I don't know if I'm really capable of explaining this I hope you're understand

Comment: The cyclic error indicates the drive may well have a hardware issue. I added additional information about this in my answer. The hardware issue is what is preventing successful format. Test the drive as suggested and it may be that the drive has essentially died.

Comment: Normally a cyclic error is either damaged drive data or a hardware error.  With the drive in the carrier, you may be able to try FDISK to delete all partitions and format the drive.    FDISK:    ........    https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/FDISK#:~:text=FDISK%20command%20in%20DOS%20and,for%20use%20with%20MS%2DDOS.